# Как сделать планировщик задач на Django для публикации постов

Tags: python, django

У меня цель - сделать планировщик постов в Телеграм.
Я сделал на Django форму, куда пользователь заводит свой текст поста, канал, картинку,  и время + дату (день недели) для публикации поста.
Вопрос, как сделать планировщик для публикации?

Из простых идей, запускать раз в минуту планировщиком Windows [Django custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands) и смотреть, если сейчас время поста, то публиковать. Из плюсов такого решения, что процесс будет запускаться новый и не будет блокировок, если в это время предыдущий запуск задачи не закончил работу. Но как-то это смотрится не очень.

Может есть более правильно решение, как это реализовать. Если описанный выше вариант не является костылем, то просьба так и написать, что это приемлемое решение.

Answer (score 0):

Одно из более правильных решений было бы использовать библиотеку Celery для создания задач планировщика в Django. Эта библиотека позволяет легко создавать и настраивать задачи, которые могут выполняться в фоновом режиме и по расписанию. Вы можете настроить задачу, чтобы она запускалась в определенное время и день недели, и выполняла код, который будет отправлять пост в Telegram. Это более предпочтительное решение, чем запуск планировщиком Windows, потому что оно интегрируется непосредственно в ваш проект Django и может быть легко настроено и мониторировать.

Comment: Celery [прекратил поддержку Windows](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/faq.html?highlight=windows#does-celery-support-windows),  а у меня к проект работает на windows машине и используется одна библиотека, которая работает только под Windows. Какую альтернативу вместо Celery лучше использовать?

Comment: Нашел что в место Celery для тех кто хочет поддержку windows есть [Dramatiq](https://dramatiq.io/cookbook.html), но как я понял он для запуска задач из списка.
Еще нашел [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html), но пока не понял как добавить из работающего приложения новый task в нем